# Receiving all manner of changing error messages

Tags: python, tkinter

I am running my program in Wing and it comes back with changing error messages. When running I get messages such as unknown option; -screen, -use, -class adn all sort of stuff that doesn't appear in the code

```
from tkinter import*

class Trip:

    def __init__(self, parent): 
        self.rating_frame = Frame(parent, width = 350, height = 320, bg = "chartreuse")
        self.rating_frame.grid_propagate(0) # to reserve space required for frame    
        self.summary_frame = Frame(parent, width = 350, height = 320, bg = "orchid")
        self.summary_frame.grid_propagate(0)          

        self.Pname = Label(self.rating_frame, parent, text = "Name:")
        self.Pname.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = E)
        self.E_name = Entry(self.rating_frame, parent, width = 20)
        self.E_name.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.names.append(E_name)        
        self.menuButton = Button(self.rating_frame, parent, text = "Continue", command = self.cleardata)
        self.menuButton.grid(row = 7, column = 1)

    def cleardata(self):
        self.rating_frame.grid_remove()
        root.update_idletasks() # Necessary on some operating systems to force the screen to refresh properly               

#main routine
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Traveller Details")
    test = Trip(root)
    root.geometry("450x350+0+0")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you give us some examples of the error messages along with the trace? If the stuff isn't in your code, it's probably in your imported modules -- which could be caused by passing bad data/arguments/etc

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 1, line 28
  Python Shell, prompt 1, line 11
  File "c:\Python34\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2604, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "c:\Python34\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2122, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-menu"

Comment: I'd have to research tkinter a bit, maybe someone else already knows the issue -- but from the trace the problem does appear to be that you are passing data into Tkinter that is not what it is looking for. Seemingly in Line 11: self.Pname = Label(self.rating_frame, parent, text = "Name:")

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
self.Pname = Label(self.rating_frame, parent, text = "Name:")
```

Either `self.rating_frame` or `parent` needs to be removed. My guess is that you need to remove `parent`, assuming that you want this label to be inside of the rating frame.